# pync interacting with tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

am python newbie here. What I am trying to do is to filter certain tweets using tweepy and its streaming function, and then push it alert me via pync.

Using the notifier function, I've noticed that all is well when the notification is pure text. However the moment there is a url in there, I no longer see a notification.

I've tried decoding/encoding it into utf-8/ascii suspecting it is an issue that has got to do with the format, and I've even tried using regex to just extract the part without the url, but nothing seems to work.

An example of the tweet I am trying to push to myself would be:

[Bukit Timah] Snorlax until 8:14:00AM at  PIE http://maps.google.com/maps?q=1.336806,103.809445 … http://sgpokemap.com

Would appreciate any help! If you need more information let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it myself! It seems like notifier cannot take in the character brackers [ and ]. All I did was to filter it out and it was A OK.